# Reduce line weight of border in Solidworks sheet format

Tags: solidworks

Is it possible to reduce line-weight (thickness) of border in Solidworks sheet format. I want to reduce the thickness of the lines shown below as I find it too much thick.

[image]

Comment: Does Solidworks have a Help system? Or instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

1. Right click in the drawing area, and then click "Edit Sheet Format", to allow you to select the lines you want to adjust
2. Open the Lines Toolbar - you can search for it if you don't have it visible
3. Change the line weight using the relevant tool

See the .gif below to show this process.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer